# C# client connection to the Apache Ignite Cluster deployed in Kubernetes

Tags: c#, kubernetes, ignite

We have a C# thick client which is required to be modified to connect with the Apache Ignite cluster nodes present in the Kubernetes. The C# thick client will run in a Windows machine outside of the Kubernetes. Can we achieve this using the TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder defined in the spring.xml configuration or using any other methods?

Got the below error in the C# thick client while accessing the load balancer ip and the discovery port,

```
[19:34:13,884][WARNING][exchange-worker-#49][TcpCommunicationSpi] Connection timed out (will stop attempts to perform the connect) [node=4dccb2bb-3258-4950-9ca2-1661c6e218cd, connTimeoutStgy=ExponentialBackoffTimeoutStrategy [maxTimeout=600000, totalTimeout=10000, startNanos=30095071382900, currTimeout=16000], failureDetectionTimeoutEnabled=true, timeout=2214, err=null, addr=/10.1.0.12:47100]
[19:34:23,913][WARNING][exchange-worker-#49][TcpCommunicationSpi] Handshake timed out (will stop attempts to perform the handshake) [node=4dccb2bb-3258-4950-9ca2-1661c6e218cd, connTimeoutStrategy=ExponentialBackoffTimeoutStrategy [maxTimeout=600000, totalTimeout=10000, startNanos=30105090262900, currTimeout=16000], err=Failed to perform handshake due to timeout (consider increasing 'connectionTimeout' configuration property)., addr=/127.0.0.1:47100, failureDetectionTimeoutEnabled=true, timeout=2447]
[19:34:23,934][SEVERE][exchange-worker-#49][TcpCommunicationSpi] Failed to send message to remote node [node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=4dccb2bb-3258-4950-9ca2-1661c6e218cd, consistentId=d435cb01-c152-489c-81a8-f3112cdc503c, addrs=ArrayList [10.1.0.12, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [/10.1.0.12:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1651673041762, loc=false, ver=2.12.0#20220108-sha1:b1289f75, isClient=false], msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridDhtPartitionsSingleMessage [parts=null, partCntrs=null, partsSizes=null, partHistCntrs=null, err=null, client=true, exchangeStartTime=1651673043426, finishMsg=null, super=GridDhtPartitionsAbstractMessage [exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=48, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=ca495ae9-b59f-4c9e-863b-2fbb34bb8907, consistentId=ca495ae9-b59f-4c9e-863b-2fbb34bb8907, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 10.68.137.15, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, hostname/10.68.137.15:0], discPort=0, order=48, intOrder=0, lastExchangeTime=1651673041420, loc=true, ver=2.12.0#20220108-sha1:b1289f75, isClient=true], topVer=48, msgTemplate=null, span=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.tracing.NoopSpan@3b224e, nodeId8=ca495ae9, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1651673043393], nodeId=ca495ae9, evt=NODE_JOINED], lastVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=0, order=1651673038156, nodeOrder=0], super=GridCacheMessage [msgId=1, depInfo=null, lastAffChangedTopVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=-1, minorTopVer=0], err=null, skipPrepare=false]]]]]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to node (is node still alive?). Make sure that each ComputeTask and cache Transaction has a timeout set in order to prevent parties from waiting forever in case of network issues [nodeId=4dccb2bb-3258-4950-9ca2-1661c6e218cd, addrs=[/10.1.0.12:47100, /127.0.0.1:47100]]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper.createNioSession(GridNioServerWrapper.java:605)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper.createTcpClient(GridNioServerWrapper.java:693)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:1264)
```

Here is the configuration,

```
<bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="clientMode" value="true"/>
    <property name="failureDetectionTimeout" value="10000"/>
    <property name="networkTimeout" value="10000"/>
    <property name="clientFailureDetectionTimeout" value="30000"/>
    <property name="clientConnectorConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.ClientConnectorConfiguration">
            <property name="host" value="127.0.0.1"/>
            <property name="port" value="47500"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="communicationSpi">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
        <property name="forceClientToServerConnections" value="true"/>
      </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="discoverySpi">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
        <property name="ipFinder">
          <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
            <property name="addresses">
              <list>
                <value>localhost:47500</value>
              </list>
            </property>
          </bean>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since that thick client is deployed outside of Kubernetes it doesn't have access to the k8s service. You will need to specify external nodes addresses explicitly for that client.

In addition, set `forceClientToServerConnections=true` option as described [here](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/running-client-nodes-behind-nat).

Comment: Thanks Alexandr Shapkin. How about using Load Balancer on this scenario as it would be tough to maintain the external nodes addresses?